# Can I group multiple domains in a routing group in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

Let's say I have the following:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => array('admin.example.com')), function()
{
    ...
});

Route::group(array('domain' => array('app.example.com')), function()
{
    ...
});

Route::group(array('domain' => array('dev.app.example.com')), function()
{
    ...
});
```

Is there any way to have multiple domains share a routing group? Something like:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => array('dev.app.example.com','app.example.com')), function()
{
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Laravel does not seem to support this.

I'm not sure why I didn't think of this sooner, but I guess one solution would be to just declare the routes in a separate function as pass it to both route groups.

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'admin.example.com'), function()
{
    ...
});

$appRoutes = function() {
    Route::get('/',function(){
        ...
    }); 
};

Route::group(array('domain' => 'app.example.com'), $appRoutes);
Route::group(array('domain' => 'dev.app.example.com'), $appRoutes);
```

I'm not sure if there is any significant performance impact to this solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think there's no performance impact to this because you're just storing it in a array variable and just padding it to the 2 declaration. Cheers!

Comment: Would this really work with `php artisan route:cache`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#route-caching

*"Closure based routes cannot be cached. To use route caching, you must convert any Closure routes to controller classes."*

Comment: I'm not sure @Fredrik, but that quote may be speaking to the actual route implementation and not the construction of the routes. In my example above, if `Route::get` referenced a controller method, it might be cacheable.

Answer (score 19):

Laravel 5.1

```
 

Route::pattern('subdomain', '(dev.app|app)');
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.example.com'], function () {
  ...
});
```

```
 

Route::pattern('subdomain', '(dev.app|app)');
Route::pattern('domain', '(example.com|example.dev)');
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.{domain}'], function () {
  ...
});
```

Comment: This is a great tip. Be aware, though, that the domain parameter will be passed as the first parameter of any child routes:
`Route::get('users/{id}', 'UsersController@show'); // id = "example.com";`

To avoid this you can always use environment variables instead:
`$domain = env('BASE_DOMAIN', 'example.com');
Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.'.$domain], function() {
    ...
});`

Answer (score 8):

You can pass on the domain name as well:

```
Route::pattern('domain', '(domain1.develop|domain2.develop|domain.com)');
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function($domain) {
        return 'This is the page for ' . $domain . '!';
    });
});
```

Just in case you need to know with which domain name the controller is called.
Tested it with Laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 4):

Interested in this also! I'm trying to register a local development + production subdomain route, for the one controller action.

i.e.

```
# Local Dev
Route::group(array('domain' => "{subdomain}.app.dev"), function() {
    Route::get('/{id}', 'SomeController@getShow');
});

# Production Server
Route::group(array('domain' => "{subdomain}.app.com"), function() {
    Route::get('/{id}', 'SomeController@getShow');
});
```

I tried:

```
# Failed
Route::group(array('domain' => "{account}.app.{top_level_domain}"), function() {
    Route::get('/{id}', 'SomeController@getShow');
});
```

But it failed.

Not a huge issue, as DesignerGuy mentioned I can just pass in a function to both routes - but it would just be more elegant if they could be grouped :)

Comment: I am attempting to solve a similar problem. Namely, to have a "ui.domain.com" and an "api.domain.com" in production, yet allow my development team to have "ui.domain.local" and "api.domain.local" for their local development environments. Support for a wild card after the sub-domain would do the trick.

The basic problem is that I am aiming to solve is to resolve conflicting routes. For example ui.domain.com/messages should return HTML and api.domain.com/messages should return JSON.

So two groups with 'domain' => 'api.(:any)' and 'domain' => 'ui.(:any)' would be ideal

Answer (score 4):

check in [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing), if you main domain is myapp, in production is `myapp.com` and in local environment is `myapp.dev` try using a `*`

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.myapp.*'), 
function()
{
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

according to [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)
in laravel 5.4+ you can use this way:

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A better answer found on Laravel discussion on the same topic is with macros. It works great for me. 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4017#issuecomment-267820459

```php
Route::macro("domain", function(array $domains, \Closure $definition) {
    foreach ($domains as $domain) {
        Route::group(['domain' => $domain], $definition);
    }
});

Route::domain(['foo.bar.dev', 'foo.bar'], function($route) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: I added a comment to this link you provided with an improvement for named routes: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4017#issuecomment-897936526

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot. I had the same 'problem'; my fix is to cycle through your subdomains with a foreach and register the routes.

Answer (score 0):

see this link. http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing

```php
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.example.com'), function()
{
    ...
});
```

or Use this package.

https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router

It help you can set where on group routing like this.

```php
Route::group(array('domain' => '{maindomain}'), function()
{
    ...
})->where('maindomain', '.+\.example\.com$');
```

Comment: this not work 

<code>
Route::group(array('domain' => '{maindomain}'), function()
{
    ...
})->where('maindomain', '.+\.example\.com$');
</code>