# Multiple Domains & one folder - how to manage sitemap.xml?

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7

I have multiple domains `example-A.com`,`example-B.com` and`example-C.com` that are all different, but they all point to the same folder on my server (The three domains are very closely connected but only administrated through a single Laravel application, for more see [Multiple websites with one Laravel installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604788/multiple-websites-with-one-laravel-installation))

Now I need for each domain a different `sitemap.xml` file.

I found in [this answer how to execute PHP inside XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21860182/2311074). With that I could dynamically change the content of the `sitemap.xml` with respect to the `url`. Will this work for crawlers and SE if they try to access the XML file? Or is there a more recommended way of doing this?

Comment: _“Will this work for crawlers and SE if they try to access the XML file?”_ - first of all, they do not access a _file_, but a _resource_, and secondly, why would it not? What your server does internally to serve the content behind _any_ URL is absolutely irrelevant to the outside world.

Comment: @misorude why is `sitemap.xml` not a file? Yes this is what I thought, but I just wasn't sure. Sorry if my question offended you.

Comment: It is a file when you look at it via your local file system. Once you start accessing it via HTTP(S) - which is what crawlers will do, since they don’t have access to the file system of your server - it stops being a file, because HTTP does not _have_ the concept of a “file”. So what the data is read from or how it is dynamically created by your web server, does not matter one bit for anyone on the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a route that's matched by `sitemap.xml` but leads to a PHP script. Then this script serves a pre-generated sitemap file, or maybe even generates it itself.
The simplest way I can imagine would be:

```
# .htaccess
RewriteRule ^/sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]

// sitemap.php
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'example-A.com':
        echo file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/sitemap-A.xml');
        break;
    case 'example-B.com':
        echo file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/sitemap-B.xml');
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

I don't know Laravel, but I'm sure there's a way to create a route that's matched by `/sitemap.xml` and served by some controller.

Comment: Thanks for this idea! Maybe its best to use the RewriteRule  based on the `{HTTP_HOST}` and then link to `sitemap-A.xml` or `sitemap-B.xml`. Then one does not need a `sitemap.php` and the switch rule.