# dynamic domain fails with free subdomains (free domains)

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain, laravel-5.4

I using Laravel 5.4. Im trying to use dynamic domains like:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{domain}.com'), function (){//routes}
```

it works well if `{domain}` is something like `example` or `test-domain` but if i wanna try to generate free subdomains or use another free domains like `sd1.example` or `example.free-domains` , it returns fail: `NotFoundHttpException` in RouteCollection.php. 
I think it is because of point `.` . Laravel cant find `.com` maybe? Because if i use

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{domain}.free-domain.com'), function (){//routes}
```

all is OK.

Is there any way to make Laravel look for `.com` from the end of string (address)? Or may be another workable solution?
So, I just need to make it possible to use point `.` in `{domain}`

Thank You very much!

Comment: so what exact code break your flow? both your examples are working? which one does not?

Comment: Doesn’t work when {domain}.com and i try to go on example.myapp.com

Comment: it is still not clear. You've wrote that *it works well* when `'domain' => '{domain}.com'` in your post

Comment: When {domain}.myapp.com => example.myapp.com & when {domain}.com => example.com is ok (domain==example), but when {domain}.com => example.myapp.com - fail (domain == example.myapp). That’s a question. I need to put example.myapp into {domain}

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603330/can-i-group-multiple-domains-in-a-routing-group-in-laravel ?

Comment: Not yet. didn’t see these solutions. I’ll try them. Thank you for links anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, i found good solution:

```
Route::pattern('tld', '(com|net|org|ru|local)');
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}.{tld}'], function () {
//
}
```

and allow point in domain:
in RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot()
    {
        app('router')->pattern('domain', '[a-z0-9.-]+');
        parent::boot();
    }
```

It works for me. Thanks!