# Laravel: How to create a route for multiple domains

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.7

In Laravel it is possible to target specific domains in routes like so:

```
Route::domain('example1.com')->group(...);
```

But how can I create a route that targets multiple domains like so:

```
Route::domain(['example1.com', 'example2.com'])->group(...);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I group multiple domains in a routing group in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603330/can-i-group-multiple-domains-in-a-routing-group-in-laravel)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Pattern for this

```
Route::pattern('subdomain', '(dev.app|app)');
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.example.com'], function () {
  ...
});
```

--

```
Route::pattern('subdomain', '(dev.app|app)');
Route::pattern('domain', '(example.com|example.dev)');
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.{domain}'], function () {
  ...
});
```